# Elasticsearch performs slowly when data size increased

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a cluster with following details:
1. OS: Windows 7 (64 bit)
2. Number of nodes: 2 (i7 processor, 8Gb RAM)
3. ES version: 2.4.4

We have created an index with following details:
1. Index size: 86 Gb
2. Number of shards: 12
3. Number of replica: None
5. Number of documents: 140 million
6. Number of fields: 15
6. For most of the fields we have set "index": "not_analyzed"
7. For few of the fields we have set "index": "no"
8. We are not executing any full-text search, aggregation or sorting
9. For 2 fields we are using fuzziness of edit distance 1

12 shards are evenly distributed on 2 nodes (6 shards each). We are running multi-search query on this cluster where each multi-search request consist of 6 individual queries.

Our queries are taking too much time to execute. From the "took" field we can see that each individual query is taking time in the range of 3-8 seconds. Rarely they are executing in milliseconds.

Avg. record count returned in result set is around 800 (max 10k records and min 10 records).

When we ran the same test on relatively small set of data (10 million records which is 7 Gb in size) then each individual query took time in the range of 50-200 milliseconds. 
Could someone suggest what might be causing our queries to run slow when index size increases?

**Update after the response of xeraa:**

1. Maybe you are also using spinning disk?

   - *Yes*
2. 800 documents (or more) sounds like a lot. Do you always need that many?

   - *Not all but few of the individual queries return a lot of docs and we do need all of them.*
3. Did you set the heap size to 4GB (half the memory available)?

   - *Yes*
4. Why 12 shards? If you only have 2 nodes this sounds a bit too much (but will probably not make a huge difference).

   - *So that we can add more nodes later (without the need of reindex) as the data grows.*
5. Maybe you can show a query? It sounds costly with your 6 individual queries

   - *Following are the 2 sample queries that are used. A total of 6 similar queries are wrapped in multi-search.*

   POST /_msearch
       {"index" : "school"}
       {
         "query": {
         "bool" : {
           "must" : [ {
             "bool" : {
               "should" : {
                 "range" : {
                   "marks" : {
                     "from" : "100000000",
                     "to" : "200000000",
                     "include_lower" : true,
                     "include_upper" : true
                  } } } } }, {
             "nested" : {
               "query" : {
                 "match" : {
                   "query" : "25 ",
                   "fields" : [ "subject.chapter" ] } },
               "path" : "subject"
             } } ] } }
       }
       {"index" : "school"}
       {
         "query":
       {
         "bool" : {
           "must" : {
             "nested" : {
               "query" : {
                 "match" : {
                   "query" : "A100123",
                   "fields" : [ "student.id" ],
                   "fuzziness" : "1"
                 } },
               "path" : "student"
             } } } }
       }

Answer (score 0):

140 million documents mean 86GB of data then I guess 10 million documents translate to less than 8GB of data. So the smaller dataset can be served from memory (at least mostly with your two 8GB nodes), while the larger dataset needs to be served from disk. Maybe you are also using spinning disk? In any case the laws of physics will make your full dataset slower than the smaller one.

Various things you could look into:

- 800 documents (or more) sounds like a lot. Do you always need that many?
- Did you set the heap size to 4GB (half the memory available)?
- Why 12 shards? If you only have 2 nodes this sounds a bit too much (but will probably not make a huge difference).
- Maybe you can show a query? It sounds costly with your 6 individual queries

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have updated the question along with your queries.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not look pretty: spinning disks, parent-child relationship, potentially big result sets, 12 shards on 2 nodes (by default every shard will calculate the top 10 results), msearch saves you roundtrips but you'll have to wait for all the queries to finish,...
Also your boolean queries look a bit unusual; you have a must with a single element or a single should clause in a must array

Comment: Going forward I would add x-pack monitoring (there's a free license) and run your queries to monitor memory, IO, queues, throuput,... Once you have identified bottlenecks, work on them